# Tkinter images with individual properties

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am trying to learn python and figured I would start with a project to learn. The problem I have is I don't really know how to word my question to find an answer online. If someone could let me know what I'm looking for then that would be great.

In Python I'm using Tkinter. I have coded it to add a new icon (it's just a `Label` (image)) but I want to have the ability to edit a set of properties on each icon I add. For example I have some properties:

```
Status
IP
ID
Location
```

And every time I add an item I want to the user to right click the icon and change the properties for that specific icon and those properties will be saved in that icon.

But if I just do:

```
def Deviceproperties():
    ID = IntVar()
    Location = StrVar()
```

then add that function to my function that adds the icon, it won't save those properties to only that device, right?

I hope you see what I mean when I say I want to research but I'm having a hard time in knowing what I need to search for here. Any links that talk about what I'm trying to do will help. even if you could just give me some key words that would help also.

I know it seems odd but I do learn better this way.

Comment: When you said *it won't save those properties to only that device*, do you mean that the properties should be the same on multiple devices? If so you will need to make a server that holds the properties.

Comment: There are way to add attributes to image objects in Python and even save them along with the image. Images also often have "metadata" associated with them which is very similar and there are standardized ways storing and reading them (which would also become part of the image).